# How to retain and pass the new state values to another router component in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have some state values using in the `App.js` as below

```
constructor(){
  super()
  this.state = {
    text: "hello world"
  }
}

handleClick() {
    this.setState({text: "good morning})
}

render() {

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={() => <Home handleClick={this.handleClick()} {...this.state}/>} />
                    <Route path="/login" component={Login} {...this.state}/>
                    />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

Inside my `Home` component I have a button click function and on clicking the `handleClick` function will trigger and the state value will change. I want to retain the new state value and pass it to `login` component as well as `Home` component after the login process is completed.

Right now when I goes to `/login` and go back to `/` the default state value is getting inside the `Home` component.

The state value is changing to new value on `onClick` function and there is no issue with that. I have the binding methods added in the `App.js` for the functions.

How can I retain the new state value to use inside `Home` component after some other router is called?

Comment: Could you show us the `Home` and `Login` components?

Comment: In the `Home` component there is just a  button with onClick function.

Answer (score 0):

Setting state in handleClick should be:

```
handleClick() {
  this.setState({text: "good morning"})
}
```

Comment: Sorry. That was a typing mistake.

Comment: The state value is changing. But when I go to some other component and come back to `Home` the new state value is not getting. It was resetting to default value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either bind the function in the constructor, or use arrow functions instead. Additionally, you need to pass the function's reference only, without calling it. That means you can't use the `()` when passing it as a prop. And one last thing, you were passing the destructured state to the Route component instead of the Login component.

```
constructor(){
  super()
  this.state = {
    text: "hello world"
  }

  // binding in constructor not needed if using arrow function
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

// arrow function not needed if binding in constructor
handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({text: "good morning})
}

render() {

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Switch>
                    <Route
                      exact
                      path="/"
                      component={() => (
                        <Home 
                          // important: this.handleClick without ()
                          handleClick={this.handleClick}
                          {...this.state}
                        />
                      )}
                    />
                    <Route
                      path="/login"
                      component={() => (
                        <Login {...this.state} />
                      )}
                    />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

Comment: Sir, I'm able to change the state value. But the issue is when I go to `Login` and com e back to `/` route the changed state value is getting. It was changed to default state value.

Comment: @Hareesh please check my edits. You were passing the prop to the Route component instead of the Login component, could that be it?

Comment: @Hareesh can you try to reproduce your problem in a JSFiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/

Write your code there until you can reproduce the same error, save it and send me the link.